# Django model choice not raising error for an invalid choice

Tags: python, django

I have an object in Django with a choice field

```python
class CustomFieldType(models.Model):
    STRING = 'STRING'
    DATE = 'DATE'
    BOOLEAN = 'BOOLEAN'
    NUMERIC = 'NUMERIC'
    EMAIL = 'EMAIL'
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (STRING, _('String')),
        (DATE, _('Date')),
        (BOOLEAN, _('Boolean')),
        (NUMERIC, _('Numeric')),
        (EMAIL, _('Email'))
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    field_type = models.CharField(choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default=STRING, max_length=10)
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('name', 'company')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

In my django console

```python
$> CustomFieldType.objects.create(name='custom_name',field_type='noError',company=mycompany)
<CustomFieldType: custom_name>
$> CustomFieldType.objects.get(name='custom_name').field_type
u'noError'
```

Why django is not raising an error (ValidationError) ? Or Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`choices`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices) option is only for pre-populating of form drop down fields; it does not enforce any validation:

> If this is given, the default form widget will be a select box with
>   these choices instead of the standard text field.

Comment: Is there any way to enforce validation?

Comment: @user1631075 The database should not be validating anything, ever. All validation should occur before data is entered into the database. If you are expecting your database to do validation then your design is malformed.

Comment: @Diemuzi That is incorrect, or we're using different meanings for the word validation.  I mean, if the db did no validation whats the point of max lengths, or integer fields vs charfields vs booleanfields vs etc. The database should be the one source of truth. An eternal law of the universe is that data outlives applications. This is why as time goes by Django adds more and more support for building database-level constraints. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/constraints/#module-django.db.models.constraints

Comment: ["... If choices are given, they’re enforced by model validation and ..."](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#choices), also see [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017675).

Comment: Are we using a different Django, for mine the validation is enforced? A given value must be in the given choices.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

Since django 2.1, setting `choices` **does** raise validation errors:

> **If choices are given, they’re enforced by [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)** and the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.

Note that, `CustomFieldType.objects.create` is not enough. You need to do something like a `model_instance.full_clean()` to raise the error. Just as mentioned in the [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects) docs

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, and I solved it by using `save()` method instead of `create()` method, and you must use `full_clean()` before it. like this:

```py
x = "your model name"()
x."field" = "value"
.
.
.
"your model name".full_clean(self = x)
"your model name".save(self = x)
```