# No Validation on Field Choices Django Postgres?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, modelchoicefield

I created a Student model with field choices. However, when I save it, it doesn't validate whether the choice is in the choices I specified in the model field.

Why doesn't it prevent me from saving a new object with a choice I didn't specify in my model?

Here is the model:

```py
class Student(models.Model):
    year_in_school = models.CharField(
        max_length=4,
        choices= [
            ('FRES', 'Freshman'),
            ('SOPH', 'Sophomore'),
        ],
    )
```

And here is the code I wrote in the shell:

```py
>>> from app.models import Student
>>> new_student = Student.objects.create(year_in_school='HACK')
>>> new_student.year_in_school
'HA'
```

Comment: I've just discovered this behavior and I'm baffled.  I expected Django to "**fail fast**" when attempting to use an invalid choice on a model.  You might find this article by Adam Johnson valuable: https://adamj.eu/tech/2020/01/22/djangos-field-choices-dont-constrain-your-data/ . I think it's safe to say this has been confusing Django users for years: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20542953/320399

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might want to read more about choices [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices). The relevant part copied below:

> If choices are given, they’re enforced by [model validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects)

Choices are not enforced at the database level. You need to perform model validation (by calling `full_clean()`) in order to check it.

`full_clean()` will not be called automatically when you call your model’s `save()` method. You’ll need to call it manually.

Comment: Is there anything I can add to my code to run `full_clean()` automatically when I try saving an object?

Comment: Yup. We can overwrite `save()` and call `full_clean()` before calling `super().save()`.

Comment: For .create() method does it perform the validation too?